# Extract dictionary key's value and assign it

Tags: python

I want to loop through a nested dictionary and assign to variables some dictionary key values. Here is my nested dictionary:

```
nested_dictionary = {

    "api": {
            "results": 4,
            "leagues": {
              "22": {
                "league_id": "22",
                "name": "Ligue 1",
                "country": "France",
                "season": "2017",
                "season_start": "2017-08-04",
                "season_end": "2018-05-19",
                "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/22.svg",
                "standings": True
              },
              "24": {
                "league_id": "24",
                "name": "Ligue 2",
                "country": "France",
                "season": "2017",
                "season_start": "2017-07-28",
                "season_end": "2018-05-11",
                "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/24.png",
                "standings": True
              },
              "157": {
                "league_id": "157",
                "name": "National",
                "country": "France",
                "season": "2017",
                "season_start": "2017-08-04",
                "season_end": "2018-05-11",
                "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/157.png",
                "standings": True
              },
              "206": {
                "league_id": "206",
                "name": "Feminine Division 1",
                "country": "France",
                "season": "2017",
                "season_start": "2017-09-03",
                "season_end": "2018-05-27",
                "logo": "https://www.api-football.com/public/leagues/206.png",
                "standings": True
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

I trying this approach

```
response_leagues = nested_dictionary["api"]["leagues"]

for league in response_leagues:
        lg_id = league.key("league_id")
        print(lg_id)
```

but my `league.key()` function is returning the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'
```

It seems that when I am looping through my nested dict each keys data type is string. Any solutions to extract needed value and assign it to variable?

Comment: what is your desire output?

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, just use this:

```
lg_id = response_leagues[league]["league_id"]
```

Instead of this:

```
lg_id = league.key("league_id")
```

When we iterate through a dictionary, we iterate through only the keys, not the values, so we need to use the original dict to get the value using the key.

Your error was occuring because you were trying to call the method .key() of a string, the league_id key.

Comment: can a list index be `string`?

Comment: When i try thr following it's return that league is string                                                  for league in response_leagues:
        lg_id = league.key("league_id")
        print(lg_id)

Comment: My mistake, forgot how iterating through dicts worked, I've fixed my answer now.

Comment: This approach return all league_id                                                                                  my return is folowwing   22
24
157
206                                                                                                                               but i need that i can store league_id for dictionary 22 in one variable. League_id of key 24 in another

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach more usable

```
def pars():
    leagues = neste_dictionary['api']['leagues']
    for id in nested_dictionary['api']['leagues']:
        lg_id = leagues[id]["league_id"]
        lg_name = leagues[id]["name"]
        lg_country = leagues[id]["country"])
        lg_logo = leagues[id]["logo"] 
        lg_season = leagues[id]["season"]
```